# ANTLR4 - using Visitor to turn syntax tree into AST

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

My task is to implement a visitor that would turn the following grammar that evaluates arithmetic expressions into AST:

```
grammar SmallC;


program :   exp
;

exp :   lexp ((op = '>' | op = '<' |op = '>=' | op = '<=' | op = '!=' | op = '==') lexp)?
;

lexp :  term ((op = '+'|op = '-') term)*
;

term:   factor((op = '%'| op = '\*'| op = '/') factor)*
;

factor  :   Number
;

Number  : [0-9]+
;
```

Currently, ANTLR creates the following tree for expression "3*6":

program -> exp -> lexp -> term -> (factor * factor) -> Number -> ( 3 * 6)

What I want is something like this:

program -> Multiplication(3,6)

I tried to get started with this by implementing a visitor function that would traverse the tree and output some data structures, but it failed miserably. Here are my classes:

Main.Java

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream("3*6");
SmallCLexer lexer = new SmallCLexer(null);
lexer.setInputStream(input);

CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
tokens.fill();

SmallCParser parser = new SmallCParser(null);
parser.setBuildParseTree(true);
parser.setTokenStream(tokens);

ParserRuleContext tree = parser.program();
MyVisitor visitor = new MyVisitor();
visitor.visit(tree);

}

}
```

MyVisitor.java

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;


public class MyVisitor extends SmallCBaseVisitor<SmallCNode> {


@Override public SmallCNode visitExp(SmallCParser.ExpContext ctx)  {
    if ( ctx.lexp().size() == 2) {
        SmallCLexp lhs = (SmallCLexp) ctx.lexp(0).accept(this);
        SmallCLexp rhs = (SmallCLexp) ctx.lexp(1).accept(this);
        String op = ctx.op.getText();
        return new SmallCExp(lhs,rhs,op);
    } else {
        visitLexp(ctx.lexp(0));
    }


}

@Override public SmallCNode visitLexp(SmallCParser.LexpContext ctx) {
    if ( ctx.term().size() == 2) {
        SmallCTerm lhs = (SmallCTerm) ctx.term(0).accept(this);
        SmallCTerm rhs = (SmallCTerm) ctx.term(1).accept(this);
        String op = ctx.op.getText();
        return new SmallCLexp(lhs,rhs,op);
    } else {
        visitTerm(ctx.term(0));
    }


}

@Override public SmallCNode visitTerm(SmallCParser.TermContext ctx) {
    if (ctx.factor().size() == 2) {
        SmallCFactor lhs = (SmallCFactor) ctx.factor(0).accept(this);
        SmallCFactor rhs = (SmallCFactor) ctx.factor(1).accept(this);
        String op = ctx.op.getText();
        return new SmallCTerm(lhs,rhs,op);
    } else {
        visitFactor(ctx.factor(0));
    }



}

@Override public SmallCNode visitFactor(SmallCParser.FactorContext ctx) {
        String fc = ctx.getText();
        return new SmallCFactor(fc);
}
```

And here are my node classes:

```
public class SmallCNode {

}


public class SmallCExp extends SmallCNode{
    SmallCLexp lhs;
    SmallCLexp rhs;
    String op;
    public SmallCExp(SmallCLexp lhs, SmallCLexp rhs, String op) {
        super();
        this.lhs = lhs;
        this.rhs = rhs;
        this.op = op;
    }
}

public class SmallCLexp extends SmallCNode {
    SmallCTerm lhs;
    SmallCTerm rhs;
    String op;
    public SmallCLexp(SmallCTerm lhs, SmallCTerm rhs, String op) {
        super();
        this.lhs = lhs;
        this.rhs = rhs;
        this.op = op;
    }
}

public class SmallCTerm extends SmallCNode{
    SmallCFactor lhs;
    SmallCFactor rhs;
    String op;
    public SmallCTerm(SmallCFactor lhs, SmallCFactor rhs, String op) {
        super();
        this.lhs = lhs;
        this.rhs = rhs;
        this.op = op;
}

}

public class SmallCFactor extends SmallCNode {
    String factor;

    public SmallCFactor(String factor) {
        super();
        this.factor = factor;
}
```

}

When I run Main.java, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    This method must return a result of type SmallCNode

    at MyVisitor.visitExp(MyVisitor.java:8)
    at MyVisitor.visitExp(MyVisitor.java:1)
    at SmallCParser$ExpContext.accept(SmallCParser.java:151)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:70)
    at SmallCBaseVisitor.visitProgram(SmallCBaseVisitor.java:20)
    at SmallCParser$ProgramContext.accept(SmallCParser.java:103)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:42)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

Now, I am very new to this thing and I realise there is probably a lot I am missing. I have no idea how to continue from here and I would really appreciate if I could get a list of things that I am missing :)

Answer (score 1):

Many of the `else` blocks in your code don't return a `SmallCNode`, which they *must*.

It shouldn't be:

```
@Override public SmallCNode visitTerm(SmallCParser.TermContext ctx) {
if (ctx.factor().size() == 2) {
    SmallCFactor lhs = (SmallCFactor) ctx.factor(0).accept(this);
    SmallCFactor rhs = (SmallCFactor) ctx.factor(1).accept(this);
    String op = ctx.op.getText();
    return new SmallCTerm(lhs,rhs,op);
} else {
    visitFactor(ctx.factor(0));
}
```

but:

```
@Override public SmallCNode visitTerm(SmallCParser.TermContext ctx) {
if (ctx.factor().size() == 2) {
    SmallCFactor lhs = (SmallCFactor) ctx.factor(0).accept(this);
    SmallCFactor rhs = (SmallCFactor) ctx.factor(1).accept(this);
    String op = ctx.op.getText();
    return new SmallCTerm(lhs,rhs,op);
} else {
    return visitFactor(ctx.factor(0));
}
```